# Difference between `docker-compose down` and Ctrl + C

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Assume, you run a multi-container Docker application which consists of a database-container and an application-container. What is the difference between the following two methods to shut it down:

**First method**
1. Open a terminal and start the application with `docker-compose up`.
2. Shut the application down with `Ctrl + C`.

**Second method**
1. Open a terminal and start the application with `docker-compose up`.
2. Open a second terminal and shut the application down with `docker-compose down`.

In my understanding, both methods should do the exact same. However, when using the second method, I usually see some exceptions in the logs of the application that it can't connect to the database when it has already been shut down, which I otherwise don't see.
What is the recommended method?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Running Ctrl+C will only stop the containers (it's actually equivalent to `docker-compose stop`) while `docker-compose down` will also remove the stopped containers and delete any networks created by the compose file.

Ctrl+C will only work however if all services are not started as detached (`docker-compose up` does not have the `-d` flag set)

As for the recommended method, it really depends on your particular use case. If you only need to stop the services, but not remove the containers, `docker-compose stop` will suffice. If you want to maybe rebuild the images or use different images, you might need to run `docker-compose down`.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's actually equivalent. I have a prebuilding process that will start a set of services in docker-compose and load a Redis instance with data (followed by a save to disk), and then wait for the docker-compose to stop. Once it stops, it will package the data. Ever since changing laptops, CTRL+C now breaks out of the script with the normal shutdown messages and a trailing "canceled" message and a non-zero return code. I now need to run "docker-compose stop" instead (which still results in a successful shutdown).

Comment: This seems to be the right answer, but it raises other questions. "What if I `Ctrl+C` and then use `docker compose up` again?" From my tests, it will re-use the stopped containers instead of creating additional new ones. (Use `docker container list -a` to check.) "What if I `Ctrl+C` and then use `docker compose down`?" From my tests it will go ahead and remove the containers, so in using `Ctrl+C` first you didn't mess up anything. Maybe you could add this information to the answer. And `docker compose …` Seems to be the [new way to do things](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-v2/).